# Django custom Form and GenericView

Tags: django, django-forms

The following code is working but I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing. I have to pass the specie_id so I can filter the breeds to the corresponding specie. I can pass the specie_id to the view but I also have the information in the Resident model ("specie").

both get() and post() have nearly the same code, passing the specie_id.

The View

```
class ResidentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Resident
    template_name = "administration/resident_form.html"
    form_class = ResidentCreateForm

    def get(self, request, pk):
        initial = self.model.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = self.form_class(instance=initial, specie_id=initial.specie.id)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        initial = self.model.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, specie_id=initial.specie.id, instance=initial)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("resident_detail", pk)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form", form})
```

The Form

```
class ResidentCreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Resident
        fields = [
            "name",
            "specie",
            "breed",
            "gender",
            "gender_status",
            "birth_date",
            "organization",
            "social_behaviors",
            "notes",
        ]
        widgets = {
            "birth_date": DateInput(attrs={"class": "flatpickr"}),
            "specie": HiddenInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.specie_id = kwargs.pop("specie_id", None)
        super(ResidentCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["specie"].initial = self.specie_id
        self.fields["breed"].queryset = Breed.objects.for_specie(self.specie_id)
```

EDIT :

@Alasdair's answer is good and I think I perfected it a little more. My form is used for the create view too. So I added a check to see if I have the specie_id in kwargs (create) or if I have to use the specie_id from the instance (update)

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.specie_id = kwargs.pop("specie_id", None)
    super(ResidentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if not self.specie_id:
        self.specie_id = self.instance.specie.id
    self.fields["specie"].initial = self.specie_id
    self.fields["breed"].queryset = Breed.objects.for_specie(self.specie_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do `self.fields["breed"].queryset = Breed.objects.for_specie(self.initial.specie_id)`, then you don't need to pass in `specie_id` to the form.

```
class ResidentCreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Resident
        fields = [
            "name",
            "specie",
            "breed",
            "gender",
            "gender_status",
            "birth_date",
            "organization",
            "social_behaviors",
            "notes",
        ]
        widgets = {
            "birth_date": DateInput(attrs={"class": "flatpickr"}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResidentCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["breed"].queryset = Breed.objects.for_specie(self.instance.specie_id)
```

Note I've removed the `specie` hidden input above, I don't think it's necessary.

The `UpdateView` takes care of passing `instance` to the form, so you can simplify the view.

```
from django.urls import reverse

class ResidentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Resident
    template_name = "administration/resident_form.html"
    form_class = ResidentCreateForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        """Redirect to resident_detail view after a successful update"""
        return reverse('resident_detail', args=[self.kwargs['pk']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be overriding the `get_form_kwargs` method in your views.

```py
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    form_kwargs.update({'specie_id': self.kwargs.get('specie_id')})
    return form_kwargs
```